# Finding resolvent kernel

Tags: functional-analysis

For $f$ is $L^2[0,1]$ define $Kf$ by $$(Kf)(x)=\int_0^1 (1+5x^2t^2)f(t)$$

Find a function $R(x,t,\lambda)$ such that solutions to the equation $$f(x)=g(x)+\lambda \int_0^1(1+5x^2t^2)f(t)dt$$ are given by $$f(x)=g(x)+\lambda \int_0^1R(x,t,\lambda)g(t)dt$$

I'm having trouble with the calculations. Here's what I'm doing:

I'm letting $a=\int_0^1f(t)dt$ and $b=\int_0^1 t^2f(t)dt$ so that

$$f(x)=g(x)+\lambda a +5\lambda bx^2$$

Therefore, $$a=\int_0^1(g(t)+\lambda a + 5\lambda t^2b)dt=\int_0^1g(t)dt+\lambda a+\frac{5\lambda b}{3}$$ Therefore, $$a-\lambda a-\frac{5 \lambda b}{3}=\int_0^1g(t)dt$$

Doing the same for $b$, I obtain $$b-\lambda b-\frac{\lambda a}{3}=\int_0^1t^2 g(t)dt$$

I'm super stuck right here I don't know what to do next. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick is to formally put $g(x)=\delta(x-y)$, the delta function, for arbitrary but fixed $y\in(0,1)$. Then we have
$$
f(x)=\delta(x-y)+\lambda \int_0^1R(x,t,\lambda)\delta(t-y)\mathrm{d}t
=\delta(x-y)+\lambda R(x,y,\lambda).
$$
On the other hand, you have derived
$$
f(x)=g(x)+\lambda a +5\lambda bx^2 = \delta(x-y)+\lambda a +5\lambda bx^2,
$$
giving
$$
R(x,y,\lambda) = a + 5bx^2.\qquad\qquad(*)
$$
Of course this is not the final solution, because $a$ and $b$ depend on $f$,
and we do not know $f$.

In any case, we can find $a$ and $b$ by using the other formulas you have derived. Namely, we have
$$
a-\lambda a-\frac{5 \lambda b}{3}=\int_0^1g(t)\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^1\delta(t-y)\mathrm{d}t=1,
$$
and
$$
b-\lambda b-\frac{\lambda a}{3}=\int_0^1t^2 g(t)\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^1t^2 \delta(t-y)\mathrm{d}t=y^2.
$$
Find $a$ and $b$ from this linear system  and substitute into $(*)$. This will give you a candidate for $R(x,y,\lambda)$. Since we have used the delta function, the manipulations we have performed are not entirely justified. However, once we have a candidate expression for $R(x,y,\lambda)$, we can explicitly check if it indeed satisfies the properties we want.

Comment: where did the $y^2$ come from?

Comment: @User69127: It is a property of the delta function that integrating $h(t)$ against $\delta(t-c)$ is like evaluating the function $h$ at $c$.